# Et la licorne. Une / La licorne un peu triste

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

*La route de Chlifa* de Michèle Marineau :

> Elle ne quitte pas des yeux cette image qui semble la fasciner. Elle
> en examine le moindre détail. Le chapeau un peu bizarre de la dame.
> (...) Les petits lapins. Le renard. Et **la** licorne. **Une** licorne un
> peu triste, avec sa tête tournée en direction des deux dames (...)

Si l'auteure a déjà parlé de la licorne, pourquoi elle emploie l'article indéfini par la suite ?

Comment: C'est **licorne** (pas lincorne) un peu avant dans le roman on dit que Mathilde regarde  [La Dame à la licorne](https://www.musee-moyenage.fr/collection/oeuvre/la-dame-a-la-licorne.html).

Comment: @None Merci beaucoup. Mais la fille qui regarde le tableau dans la maison d'Antoine Milad s'appelle Maha, elle est libanaise.

Answer (score 7):

« Elle examine la licorne » : elle examine la licorne qui se trouve sur l'image, pas une autre. Il n'y a qu'une seule licorne sur cette image. De même pour « les petits lapins », « le renard », « la dame » etc. ils sont tous définis par rapport à l'image que Maha est en train de regarder.

Ensuite l'auteure présente la licorne de l'image par rapport à l'espèce licorne. Le présentatif *c'est* est sous-entendu : « (c'est) une licorne un peu triste ». La licorne de l'image n'est plus qu'une licorne parmi d'autres licornes.

On peut comparer :

- (1) C'est **une** licorne un peu triste.
- (2) C'est **la** licorne un peu triste **de la Dame à la licorne**.

(1) La licorne n'est pas définie.
(2) La licorne est définie.

Comment: Merci. Serait-il possible de continuer à parler de cette licorne définie, sans sous-entendre _c'est_ ? _Le renard. Et la licorne. **La** licorne un peu triste..._ Ou écrire ceci : _C'est la licorne un peu triste._ Je pense que non.

Comment: Ça n'aurait pas tout à fait le même sens.  « Le renard. Et la licorne. La licorne un peu triste...  »  : je ne suis pas vraiment sûr qu'il s'agisse de la même licorne (bien sûr si on connaît l’œuvre on sait qu'il s'agit d'une seule et même licorne mais Maha ne connaît pas l’œuvre).   Si je dis « c'est la licorne un peu triste », j'implique qu'il y en a une autre qui n'est pas triste (ou qui a une autre particularité par laquelle je peux la définir).